# При попытке подключения к VK API - 10060

Tags: python, вконтакте

Хочу работать с vk_api на питоне. При попытке подключения к своей странице во ВКонтакте идёт долгая прогрузка в консоли, затем вылетает:

```
[WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера
```

Это одна часть всей ошибки. Вот сам код:

```
import vk_api

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi('тут логин', 'тут пароль')
vk_session.auth()
vk = vk_session.get_api()
vk.wall.post(message='Hello world!')
```

Код начинает долгую загрузку на моменте "vk_session.auth()".

Comment: а вы зарегистрировали приложение в вк?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, это из-за того, что Вы живете в стране, в которой запрещен данная социальная сеть. Для этого нужно использовать Proxy/VPN/(Tor).

Comment: Да нет, это работает по другому, теперь нужно вместо входа передавать токен, я это сделал, и даже получилось на свою страницу выложить пост с помощью бота. Так и не понял в чём была ошибка..